# Ajax won't get selected option from select dropdown

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

What I want to do-
I'm trying to create a page where you have a list of clients, you select one, and Ajax loads a data table of its information.

What I'm doing-
I'm starting small by hashing out my client selection and trying to get Ajax to function in correlation.

Code:

```
<%  select_list = []
    @clients.each do |f|
    select_list << f.name
  end
%>


<%= select_tag 'client', options_for_select(select_list) %>
<%= submit_tag 'Show', :id => "show" %><br/>

<div id="load-zone" style="width:500; height:300;">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
  });
  var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='/images/load.gif' alt='loading...' width='40px' />";

//  load() functions
  var selID=document.getElementById("client");
  var loadUrl=selID.options[selID.selectedIndex].text;


  $("#show").click(function(){
    alert(loadUrl);
    $("#load-zone")
      .html(ajax_load)
      .load("/reports/ref_table_template?client=", loadUrl, "#data_table");
  });
</script>
```

I have also tried putting this in place of the two 'var' lines after `// load() functions`:

```
var loadUrl = $("#client option:selected").text();
```

And:

```
var loadUrl = $("#client").val();
```

What I expect-
The page actually loading is another issue, but with the alert in there, I should see a message window pop up with the name of the client I have selected from the drop-down.  IE, if the drop down contained ["Steve", "Jim", "Pete"] then when I select "Pete" and click the button, I should get a message box that also says "Pete".

What I'm getting-
Every single time I hit the submit button, no matter what method I try, I get "Steve" (the first option).

How can I change this so that `loadUrl` actually contains the selected item?

System specs-
Using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit
Ruby 1.8.7
Rails 3.0.20

Browser-
Google Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see where I went wrong earlier now.  This should do the trick.

You need to get `loadUrl` inside the click event.  You were getting it at the beginning, so getting the first value, and then not getting it again.  This code will get the value each time you click `#show`...

```
$("#show").click(function(){
    loadUrl = $("#client").find(":selected").text();
    alert(loadUrl);
    $("#load-zone")
        .html(ajax_load)
        .load("/reports/ref_table_template?client=" + loadUrl, "#data_table");
});
```

Comment: Good point- I actually changed it just now to (EDIT for typo) .load("/reports/ref_table_template", {client: loadUrl }, "#data_table"); and that works- but that's not the problem I have.  The problem I'm trying to solve is that no matter what option I select from the select box, it always sends the first option.  Referring back, If I select "Pete" or "Jim", Ajax returns "Steve" every time.

Comment: If it's requesting the correct information in the ajax call then your server script is wrong, not the ajax call.

Comment: `$("#show").click(function(){
    alert(loadUrl);
    $("#load-zone")
      .html(ajax_load)
      .load("/reports/ref_table_template?client=", loadUrl, "#data_table");`

The second line- "alert(loadUrl);" should bring up a message box that tells me what the value of "loadUrl" is.  If the ajax call works, it will show me the item I just selected from the dropdown.  Instead, it always shows me the first item.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding how it works, and I've got the alert in the wrong place.  Does the form have to submit before the ajax call can find out which option was selected?

Comment: That was my bad - sorry.  I see clearly now what the issue is.  The above change should help :)

Comment: Days like this I feel...  Simple...  All of the tricks I tried previously are working now, all I had to do was put them **inside** the click event.  How did I not see that?!  Time for sleep!  Can't thank you enough, though!

Comment: No problem.  I wish I'd clocked it earlier myself!  Glad to help :)